# How to find xpath in mobile app using appium

Tags: android, xpath, selenium-webdriver, appium

I tried using Find element by id but it is not inserting required data. 
Then I used Find element by xpath `//android.widget.ScrollView[0]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[0]/android.widget.TextView[0]/ndroid.widget.TextView[1]/android.widget.EditText[2]")).sendKeys("Check@localmail.com");`

but still it is not working.[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to insert email id. It is nor showing "id". So I tried with using above xpath but still it is not inserting.

Comment: I have added image... kindly view it if it make my question clear please give me solution

Answer (score 13):

Please use this Xpath , I hope this solves your problem:

```
By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@text='Email ID']")
```

Comment: would you be kind enough to help me understand to get to a solution for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39484982/access-toggle-button-in-android-settings-using-appium-whlie-client-is-written-in

Answer (score 4):

A better way of doing this is as follows -

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//EditText[contains(@text,'Edit ID')]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

u can do it in another way ,u know that there are 5 textfields , hence write the code as below.

driver.findelements(By.tagname("textfield")).get(0).sendkeys("abc@gmail.com"));

this means that you are trying to pass the abc@gmail.com value in the first text field "get(0)".

Comment: and i guess you need to update your appium version to the latest one or try using uiautomator to inspect elements.

Comment: I tried but it is giving me invalid locator. Moreover I have 1.0.0.3 (orion) version and uiautomator shows "id" but when I use it in code, system(appium) does not insert email id.

Answer (score 0):

Find xpath of mobile app using contains

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, 'Call')]")).isDisplayed())
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the available properties - index and class name, you can try with the below xpath

```
//android.widget.EditText[@index='2']
```