# Access toggle button in Android settings using appium whlie client is written in groovy and java

Tags: java, android, groovy, appium, java-client

> It's not a duplicate.

I am writing automation in [Appium](http://appium.io/). I am fairly new to automation concept and `Appium` it self. I am using java-client.

I have a scenario in which my android app for which I am writing automation, has to take android permission. My application navigates to following setting page of Android Settings as shown below.

[image]

To automate clicks on this page I have created a Page Object which would represent this screen. in this scenario I am only interested in toggling the [Switch](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html) and to learn how to get it's state.

I could get resource id for the [UI Automator Viewer](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html) something like this.

[image]

So my initialization is something like this to access the switch Widget.

```
SwitchID { $("#switchWidget") }
```

Apparently, When i run the feature file, `Appium` is not able to find this switch widget. But I can automate other widget inside the application I am working on. but I can't get anything on this setting screen of android.

Any help would be highly regarded.
Thanks

Comment: would need to understand the POM you are following and how is the widget accessed by your application. There is very less info in the question in that regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access any visible component on UI. Be it buttons/ switches or whatever.
There are several ways to access an element using Appium/ Selenium driver - By name/ id/ xpath, etc.
Use UIAutomator to capture that visible element's id/name/ content desc and you're done!
In your case, as I can see in UIAutomator screenshot - you are getting both id and name. So you can use any of them to click your desired element.
 
(You can refer to your relevant groovy/java syntax from Appium)
http://appium.io/introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

Using the java-client I would get the switch by class name. Something like this:
`driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.Switch"))`

Not sure about the groovy client, but it's probably similar.

Comment: Thank you TinyTimZamboni

Answer (score 0):

What if the switch is checked already? If you tap you will disable it...

Try:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.Switch[@resource-id='android:id/switchWidget' and @checkable='true']")
```

This will only get your element when is checkable